# How to customize the angular-material-extensions/select-country

Tags: angular

I'm developping the angular frontend of an existing API and I'm using **angular-material-extensions/select-country** to implement the country selection dropdown. The implementation was done and client was satisfied with how good the @angular-material-extensions/select-country looks. But I'm facing a problem when connecting the country selection to the API. For in the api, countries are designed a different way, following this interface pattern:

```
 country interface {
    "code": number,
    "message": String,
    "result": [
    {
     "name": String,
     "refDatas": [
       {
         "code": number,
         "name": String, 
         "translated_To_French": String
         "translated_To_German": String
         "translated_To_Spanish": String
         "translated_To_Portuguese": String
       }
     ]
   }
   ]
}
```

But the @angular-material-extensions/select-country library's interface is like this:

```
country interface {
  name: string;
  alpha2Code: string;
  alpha3Code: string;
  numericCode: string;
  callingCode: string;
}
```

Obviously the library needs this 5 properties to function and I just don't know how to match it to the API payload? As you can see in both sides we have "name", so name property causes no problem, but for the **alpha2Code**, **alpha3Code**, **numericCode** and **callingCode** I don't know the role that they play in the library.
The only solution was to assign "*code*" to "*numericCode*", but it caused the app to break and I can't change the API design about countries either.
Any help to bypass this impediment is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have way broad to achieve. First define two interfaces, one that matches the API's payload and the second that matches the library's interface. You should have these two:

```
export interface apiCountries {
  code: number,
  message: String,
  result: [
  {
   name: String,
   refDatas: [
     {
       code: number,
       name: String,
       translated_To_French: String,
       translated_To_German: String,
       translated_To_Spanish: String,
       translated_To_Portuguese: String
     }
   ]
 }
 ]
}
export interface libraryCountries {
      name: string,
      alpha2Code: string,
      alpha3Code: string,
      numericCode: string,
      callingCode: string,
    }


apiFetched : apiCountries = {
  code: 0,
  message: '',
  result: [
     {           
       name: '',
       refDatas: [   
         {
           code: 0,
            name: '',
            translated_To_French: '',
            translated_To_German: '',
            translated_To_Spanish: '',
            translated_To_Portuguese: ''
          }
         ],
       }
    ],
}

data : libraryCountries = {
    name: '',
    alpha2Code: '',
    alpha3Code: '',
    numericCode: '',
    callingCode: '',            
}  

dataCountries: libraryCountries[]
predefinedCountries : libraryCountries[]
```

Then create getCountries() function:

```
getCountries() {
      return this.service.serviceMethodToFetchCountries()
      .pipe(
        map((response) => response)
      ).subscribe( (obj) => {
        for (const nat of Object.values(obj)[2]) {
             for (const data of nat.refDatas) {
               this.data = {
                name: data.name,
                alpha2Code: data.name.substring(0,2),
                alpha3Code: data.name.substring(0,3),
                numericCode: data.code.toString(),
                callingCode: ''
              };
              this.dataCountries.push(this.data);
              this.predefinedCountries = this.dataCountries;
             }

        }; }

       )

    }
```

And make:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getCountries()
}
```

And then pass the **predefinedCountries** variable to [countries] inside the template i.e `[countries]="predefinedCountrie"`.

Comment: It worked like a charm, you're like a genius.